# NodeTool@0 Task Fails on Hosted Agent

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am running a pipeline on a macos-12 agent which has a NodeTool@0 task

```
- task: NodeTool@0
    inputs:
       versionSource: 'spec'
       versionSpec: '16.x'
       checkLatest: false
```

`

This link: https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/macos/macos-12-Readme.md
mentions that NodeJS 16.8.1 is cached in macos-12 hosted agents

However, I often (but not always) get the following error when running my pipeline:
 `##[error]Unable to create directory '/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/16.18.1/x64'. EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/opt/hostedtoolcache'`

Why? And what can I do to prevent this error?

Thank you
Kiko

Comment: Hi @Kiko Aumond, I find similar issue here: https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/1362. To avoid other task influence, could you kindly use the NodeTool@0 only with the agent macos-12 for a try? And please notice the indention format of the yaml. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Kiki, could you kindly tell the latest information? Do you resolve the issue yourself? If  so, you could share your answer here. That may help others who meet the issue in the future.

Comment: HI @AntoniaWu-MSFT, yes, as  mentioned in the link you posted, it was simply an issue of setting the permissions in the /opt folder.  I guess not all agents have write permissions enabled by default on that folder.  Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Kiko, thanks so much for your reply! Could you post your solution as an Answer and you could mark your answer in the issue. This would help others who may meet the issue in the future. :>